# Vue element UI tree Personalizado

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js

Requiero personalizar el componente  de Element Ui pero no se como añadirle los compoenentes que dependen del mismo
algo asi como esto:

```
  <el-tree
    :data="data"
    show-checkbox
    node-key="id"
    :props="producProp"
  >
      <el-checkbox v-model="node.checked"></el-checkbox>
  </el-tree>
```

me gustaria personalizar tanto el checkbox como el label, tienen alguna idea?

Comment: Que componente es ese? de donde lo sacaste? que dice la documentacion del mismo?

Comment: En la documentacion del componente solo te recomienda usar slots pero no te dice especificamente como quedarian los slots

Comment: O sea, este es un problema particular de ese componente. Habria que ver que hace bien, que podes meter en los slots, y que hace el mismo. Yo no conozco el mismo.